# access pages without extensions except one page htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a website for example :
https://website.com

It loads pages as :

```
https://website.com/page1.html
https://website.com/page2.html
https://website.com/page3.html
https://website.com/page4.html
```

I would like to open above pages without extension except page2.html, that is :

```
https://website.com/page1
https://website.com/page2.html
https://website.com/page3
https://website.com/page4
```

If user explicitly enters :

```
https://website.com/page1.html
```

Then too, it should be redirected to:

```
https://website.com/page1
```

Same for page3 and page4

I applied below rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

It is able to open pages without extension, that is :

```
https://website.com/page1
https://website.com/page2
https://website.com/page3
https://website.com/page4
```

But when I enter:

```
https://website.com/page1.html
```

It gets opened, but what am in need of is, when I open:

```
https://website.com/page1.html
```

It should be automatically redirected to

```
https://website.com/page1
```

This condition should be for all the pages except page2.html

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following *before* your existing rewrites.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/page2.html
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html /$1 [L,R=301]
```

May need modification depending on exactly what page1/2/3/4 are. The `/?` bit in the pattern for the `RewriteRule` is only there to make it generic for both `htaccess` files and the main Apache configuration files. If you only intend to us this in `htaccess` files you can remove it.